# get index of current hovered li respect to visible li only - jquery hover

Tags: jquery, indexing, hover, html-lists, visible

There are 5 li element and one of them say third li is hidden.Is there a way to apply filter before getting index so that fourth element's index should show 2 instead of 3.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-1.4.2.js'></script>
        <script>
            $(window).load(function() {
                    jQuery('.addchar').live('hover', function(event) {
                        $("#result").html("Index is:" +$(this).index() );
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li class="addchar">one </li>
                    <li class="addchar">two </li>
                    <li class="addchar" style="display:none"> three</li>
                    <li class="addchar">four </li>
                    <li class="addchar">five </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="result"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using the [visible selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/):

```
$('.addchar:visible').live( ...
```

EDIT:

Too bad, you could try an alternative approach if that is an option for you:

```
$(function() {
    $('.addchar:visible').each(function(index) {
        $(this).hover(function() {
            $("#result").html("Index is: " + index);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but same result.Is it possible to get total no of elements that are hidden between 0 and current hovered element's index. If yes then index can be calculated.

Comment: Added an alternative approach.

Answer (score 0):

As foreach method iterates every element it became slow when element size rises.I searched and got it working.Thanks to this [link](http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/12/how-to-get-anything-you-want-part-2).

```
jQuery('.addchar').live('hover', function (event) {
var cInd = $(this).index();//current index including hidden element
var hidLen = $(this).parent().children("li:lt(" + cInd + "):not(:visible)").length;//total hidden before hovered element
var index = cInd - hidLen;
$("#result").html("Current index :" + cInd +"<br>Tot Hidden Before Current:" + hidLen+"<br> Actual Index:"+index);
});
```